# Solovay's lemma for a non-computable sum

Tags: computability, random

I'm currently learning about computability theory, specifically about Martin-Löf randomness. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1859) by M. Pancia, I came across an interesting result called Solovay's lemma (below, I give the relevant definitions needed to understand this lemma):

> Let $V_1,V_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of uniformly $\Sigma_0^1$ sets and $X\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ Martin-Löf random. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(V_n) < \infty$, then $X$ lies in only finitely many $V_n$.

The paper cites [this other paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1015345756) as its source for this lemma. However in this paper, they make the additional assumption that $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(V_n)$ is computable.

When I tried to prove this lemma in the setting of Pancia's paper, I also seem to need that $S$ is computable. The reason I need this is because in the original proof, they essentially construct an algorithm which, given input $M$, computes a $k$ such that $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\mu(V_n)<1/M$ and such an algorithm seems impossible to construct if $S$ is not computable.

So my question is: Is this an oversight by the author, meaning that $S$ does need to be computable, or is there some way to prove Solovay's lemma without this computability assumption?

Thanks in advance!

--

Some definitions used in the paper:

- Fix a Gödel numbering and let $\varphi_{e}(x)$ be the output of the program with Gödel number $e$ running with input $x$ (if it halts).
- Letting $X$ be an element of $2^\mathbb{N}$, we define $\varphi_{e}^X(x)$ as above, except $X$ is used as an oracle in the computation.
- For any Gödel number $e$, define $$S_e = \{ X\in 2^\mathbb{N}: \varphi_{e}^X \text{ halts on input }0 \}$$
- We say a sequence $V_n$ of $\Sigma_0^1$
  sets is effectively open or uniformly $\Sigma_0^1$
  if $V_n = S_{f(n)}$,
  where $f$ is a total recursive function.
- A set $S$ is effectively null if $S \subseteq \cap_{n} V_n$, where $V_n$ are uniformly $\Sigma_0^1$ and $\mu(V_n)<2^{-n}$.
- $X\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ is Martin-Löf random if $X$ does not lie in any effectively null set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the assumption that $\Sigma_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(V_n)$ is computable. This is a standard result in algorithmic randomness and you can find the result in any textbook on the field. For instance, it is theorem 6.2.8 in *Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity* by Downey and Hirschfeldt.

Here's the idea of the proof. First, let's assume that $\Sigma_{n = 1}^\infty \mu(V_n) < 1$ (if not, just throw away a finite number of the $V_n$'s so that the sum is less than 1). Now set $U_n$ to be the set of reals which occur in at least $2^n$ of the $V_m$'s. This sequence of $U_n$'s is uniformly $\Sigma^0_1$ and its intersection contains all those reals which occur in infinitely many $V_m$'s. And $\mu(U_n) < 2^{-n}$, basically because each element of $U_n$ gets "counted" $2^n$ times in $\Sigma_{m = 1}^\infty \mu(V_m) < 1$. So the $U_n$'s form a Martin-Löf test.